# CMake macro inclusion issue

Tags: macros, cmake, include, target

The aim is to have small and useful libraries included into a main application.

I create a `CMakeLists.txt` file to create three different library : image, utils_dir and utils_geom. The thing that bother me is the horrible redundancy with the target definition. So I tried to create some macro and I'm confronted to an inclusion issue.

The pattern of my project is presented below.

```
src/CMakeLists.txt (main CMakeLists including subdirs)
src/cmake/Macro.cmake (containing macro)
src/libs/core/CMakeLists.txt (library def and macro use)
```

**I can't include my Macro.cmake** file which contain the macro definition.

With the following code in the top level CMakeLists.txt (in src/) :

```
include(Macro.cmake)
test_macro()
```

And in the Macro.cmake :

```
macro( test_macro )
    MESSAGE("Success !")
endmacro
```

I've got :

```
CMake Error at libs/core/CMakeLists.txt:8 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    Macro.cmake


CMake Error at libs/core/CMakeLists.txt:9 (test_macro):
  Unknown CMake command "test_macro".
```

Did someone is using a likely configuration ?

Comment: *Unrelated problems should go into different questions*. `I can't include my Macro.cmake` - `find_package()` is not intended for just include the script. use `include(Macro.cmake)` instead. Also, you has weird assignment to *CMAKE_MODULE_PATH* variable. If you want it to contain a **list**, pass every element as *distinct* parameter: `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake" "var")`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to edit my question for only the include issue. I already used the include(Macro.cmake), I'll describe a little more what is it doing.

Comment: Adjusting variable *CMAKE_MODULE_PATH* is still needed for `include()` to find the script inside your source tree.

Comment: Thanks, it works. It seems you don't have to tell the .cmake extension (include(Macro)).